# Unable to Stop the Service?

Tags: android, service

i am using media player to play Sound.When the Custom  Toolbar image is pressed from the Second Activity the Audio Service is not Stopping.

```
 public class ClassMain extends AppCompatActivity {

        LinearLayout linearclass1;
        Toolbar toolbar;
        TextView customtexttoolbartitle;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        final static int Delay = 1000;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_6_parts);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar);
            customtexttoolbartitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar_title);
            customtexttoolbartitle.setText("Select Your Grade");

            playAudioWithDelay();
            linearclass1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_class_1);
            linearclass1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ClassMain.this, ClassOneSubjectList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    startService(v);

                }
            });
        }

        public void startService(View view) {

            startService(new Intent(this, UseBackgroundSoundService.class));

        }


        public void playAudioWithDelay() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sound();
                }

            }, Delay);

        }


        void sound() {


            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.got);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        }


    }
```

This is my Second Activity

public class ClassOneSubjectList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView customtexttoolbartitle;
    ImageView customtoolbarimage;
    private FeatureCoverFlow mCoverFlow;
    private CoverFlowAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BookEntity> mData = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private TextSwitcher mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_one_subject_list);


        customtexttoolbartitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar_title);
        customtexttoolbartitle.setText("Select Subject");
        customtoolbarimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar_image);
        customtoolbarimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar);
        customtoolbarimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ClassOneSubjectList.this, ClassMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                stopService(new Intent(ClassOneSubjectList.this, UseBackgroundSoundService.class));

            }
        });


        mData.add(new BookEntity(R.mipmap.social, R.string.title1));
        mData.add(new BookEntity(R.mipmap.maths, R.string.title2));
        mData.add(new BookEntity(R.mipmap.science, R.string.title3));
        mData.add(new BookEntity(R.mipmap.nepali, R.string.title4));

        mTitle = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mTitle.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
            @Override
            public View makeView() {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ClassOneSubjectList.this);
                TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_subject_book_title, null);
                return textView;
            }
        });
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_top);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        mTitle.setInAnimation(in);
        mTitle.setOutAnimation(out);

        mAdapter = new CoverFlowAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.setData(mData);
        mCoverFlow = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
        mCoverFlow.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        stopService(new Intent(ClassOneSubjectList.this, UseBackgroundSoundService.class));
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ClassOneSubjectList.this, ChooseExerciseSyllabus.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                }


            }
        });

        mCoverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(new FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolledToPosition(int position) {
                mTitle.setText(getResources().getString(mData.get(position).titleResId));

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolling() {
                mTitle.setText("");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return super.stopService(name);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        stopService(new Intent(ClassOneSubjectList.this, UseBackgroundSoundService.class));
    }


}
```

my background Service Activity

```
public class UseBackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String Tag = null;
    MediaPlayer player;


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final static int Delay = 1000;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.got);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
        playAudioWithDelaysound();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();


    }

    public void playAudioWithDelaysound() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UseBackgroundSoundService.this, UseBackgroundSoundService.class);
                startService(intent);
                player.start();


            }

        }, Delay);

    }


}
```

The Service is Stopping on backpressed,but it is not stopping from the CustomToolbar Image(Back) from the Second Activity which intent to First Activity??please help

Comment: I guess your problem is that you create a mediaPlayer in your Activity and another one in your service and both get started. You stop the service but I think the mediaPlayer in your activity is playing...

Comment: can i use only the Service to get start and Stop media player in MyBackgroundService class. not creating the media player in the MainActivity.

Comment: usually it should, just try it..

Comment: @ Opiatefuchs  sir i found error but not able to solve ,It is Actually with  media player onCreate Method on MainActivity.Sir when we click the back Imge then the Oncreate of main Activity is Called,and that is responsible to play sound.can we disable the service on mainActivity when we press the image?